# How to force HTML page to update in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

This might be a simple question but I have been searching for an answer to no avail. The code below is supposed to read five strings then update the page with these values, one value at a time. However, this worked only in Firefox (i.e. the document is updated after each iteration). Other browsers just showed the last value!! Anyone can help me understand this weird behavior?

```
<h1 id="test"></h1>
<script>
  for(var i = 0; i<5; i++){
     var x = window.prompt("Write something..");
     document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
  }
</script>
```

Edit: Thanks everyone. setTimeout worked fine. what is the best alternative to window.prompt? Forms?

Comment: firefox (since quantum) seems to allow rendering where no other browsers would - this make firefox better, but allows poor code such as this to "seem to be the right thing to do" ... modal dialogs like alert/prompt etc are never a good solution

Comment: your for loop and inner html is fine. The problem is the prompt. Dont use prompt, bad UI

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question, do not add on to this question which now makes it too broad and will be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a chance for browser to do its job. When you are in a loop, you are occupying browser. Following example works in chrome:

```
<h1 id="test"></h1>
<script>
function askOne() {
  var x = window.prompt("Write something..");
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
}

function ask() {
  for(var i = 0; i<5; i++){
    setTimeout(askOne, 0);
  }
}

setTimeout(ask, 0);
</script>
```

With `setTimeout()`, you are giving a change to browser to do somethings. Which it may or may not use.

While it might be ok for some local `test.html`, in real life, one does not do it this way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What would be the other way? forms?

Comment: I don't know, that depends on your goals. For real world applications, you would be using some browser side framework like `Vue.js`, `React`, `Angular` etc. there are so many. Also you will have to decide your server side, twice as more than browser side, if browser side only `JavaScript`, server side is unlimited by language, like `Django` in `Python`, there are many in `PHP`...

Answer (score 0):

The old school way is to use `setInterval` or `setTimeout`.

```
function updatePage(x) {
  // perform some change to the DOM, e.g.
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x;
}
// This will call updatePage(x) every 5000ms
setInterval(() => {updatePage(x)}, 5000);
```

Pretty sure this is deprecated though. And what you probably want to do is bind an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the input element that x comes from.